# How is the rem unit rendered in CSS?

Tags: css

About the rem unit introduced since CSS3, is it rendered only when a page refreshed? If resizing a web page for responsive testing, will a text, whose font size is defined as the rem unit, also be resized dynamically?

Comment: No, why would it? The rem isn't relative to the size of the browser window. Are you getting that mixed up with viewport units?

Comment: No, I'm not asking view port or media query, but only the rem unit itself.

Comment: You sure about that? Because the rem unit has absolutely nothing to do with the size of the browser window.

Comment: Unrelated to font size values expressed in rem (which are highly recommended) and which is the subject of your question, Media Queries expressed with rem unit are badly implemented. See difference between Chr and Fx in https://fvsch.com/code/bugs/rem-mediaquery/ for example :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rem` references to the root font size defined in `html` element. So if you change your font-size dynamically the elements will be resized, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

The rem size is based on your html font-size. Look at the code below (or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qaqfo4aa/2/)).

HTML :

```
<p>
  Lorem
</p>

<p>
  Ipsum
</p>

<p>
  Dolor
</p>

<p>
  Sit
</p>

<p>
  Amet
</p>
```

CSS :

```
html {
  font-size: 24px;
}

p:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

p:nth-child(4) {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

p:nth-child(5) {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  html {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```